# MVC C# - FluentValidation Composite Validator for multiple AbstractValidator<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I have an MVC application that has many `AbstractValidator<T>` per view model. This is by design because I use `SimpleInjector` to inject queries to hit our database and I don't want to have constructor over injection in one validator. I created the class below that is the validator for every view model, but it does not call my `When` and other custom validation rules, only the simple rules are called. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class CompositeValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
  {
    private ICollection<IValidator> _validators = new List<IValidator>();

    public CompositeValidator(IEnumerable<IValidator<T>> validators = null)
    {
      if (validators == null) return;

      foreach (var validator in validators)
        {
        _validators.Add(validator);

        var enumerator = validator.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
          AddRule(enumerator.Current);
        }
      }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<T> context)
    {
      var errorsFromOtherValidators = _validators.SelectMany(x => x.Validate(context).Errors);

      return new ValidationResult(errorsFromOtherValidators );
    }
  }
```

Here is an example of two validators

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonVm>
  {
    public PersonValidator()
    {
      RuleFor(model => model.FirstName).NotEmpty();
      RuleFor(model => model.LastName).NotEmpty();
    }
  }

  public class PersonMustBeRegisteredValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonVm>
  {
    private readonly IQuery<PersonExists> _query;

    public PersonMustBeRegisteredValidator(IQuery<ReturnPerson> query)
    {
      _query = query;

      Custom(model =>
        {
          var person = _query.Select(new { model.Id });

          if (person == null) return new ValidationFailure("Id", "Person does not exist");

           return null;
        });
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

this actually works. I found a validation interceptor I forgot about that was not firing my validation.